# how to mock a constant while using jest tests a react class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

**options.isShow is always false so render() just return null, and i don't know how to mock options.isShow to true;**

```
// a.js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import merge from 'lodash-es/merge';
export let options = {
  isShow: false,
  //....
};
export default class Button extends Component {
  constructor(props) {


    super(props);
  }
  renderBtn() {
    //...
  }
  render() {
    const {data = {}} = this.props;
    // console.log(options.isShow) // false
    merge(options, data);
    return options.isShow
      ? this.renderBtn()
      : null;
  }
}

// a.spec.js
import Button from 'a.js';
jest.mock('lodash-es/merge', () => jest.fn(fn => fn));
describe('Button', () => {
  it('a', done => {
    const ButtonI = new Button({
      data: {},
    });
    ButtonI.renderBtn = jest.fn();
    ButtonI.render();
    expect(ButtonI.renderBtn).toBeCalled();
    done();
  });
})
```

**I try to mock like this, but it's not work, isShow is still false while jest a.spec.js;**
in this way, options.isShow is true in a.spec.js's console, but in a.js'console is fasle.

```
// a.spec.js
import * as ButtonAll from 'a.js';
jest.mock('lodash-es/merge', () => jest.fn(fn => fn));
describe('Button', () => {
  it('a', done => {
    const Button = ButtonAll.default;
    ButtonAll.options = {
      isShow: true,
      // ....
    }
    // console.log(ButtonAll.options.isShow) // true
    const ButtonI = new Button({
      data: {},
    });
    ButtonI.renderBtn = jest.fn();
    ButtonI.render();
    expect(ButtonI.renderBtn).toBeCalled();
      done();
  });
})
```

Comment: How did you change the value of `options.isShow` in your code?

Comment: using 'lodash-es/merge'; render() {
    const {data = {}} = this.props;merge(options, data);
    // console.log(options.isShow) // false
    return options.isShow
      ? this.renderBtn()
      : null;
  }

Comment: Please update the code in your post

Comment: done uuuuuuuuuu

Comment: Don't mock `lodash`, try using https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/ render your component with different props